# Allow zero or one occurance of string in argument (but not more)

Tags: macros

In the following MWE, I try to capture a particular string (`\at` in this string) which splits my input argument. I want to use the parser to allow the case when the `\at` is not in the argument, but not allow two or more occurrences of `\at`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@split#1\at#2\@endsplit{#1 -- #2}
\long\def\split#1{\@split#1\@endsplit}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\split{Hello \at \[ A \] \paragraph{Testing}

  \textit{worlds}

  Working!
}

% This is also OK
\split{\split{ Hello \at another} \at \split{ something \at World}}

% % How to allow this form producing "Hello ???" for example
% \split{Hello}

% % and issue error for this one
% \split{Hello \at another \at World}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't figure out a way without defining `\at` which is problematic in my case because I think I have to do in a group to allow nesting `\split`, but I need to avoid creating superfluous groups. I can also test if the argument is empty, but then the arguments cannot be long as in the previous example (I think).

Comment: Are you willing and able to work with a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: `\def{\at{...\let\at=\relax}` will only work once.  You will have to reset it each time.

Comment: As @Mico noted, can you use LuaLaTeX? UTF-8 with `fontspec`? One thing that is possible, is to use an otherwise-useless character (not macro) act as the delimiter, then test for it using a package such as `xstring`. I use the generic currency symbol `¤` for this purpose, although it might not work for you.

Comment: @Thanks Mico and rallg. I can't use LuaLaTeX. I would like to stick to tex-based solutions.

Comment: why not simply `\def\split#1{#1} \def\at{-- }` which seems to handle all the examples?

Comment: TeX strips off curly braces that surround an entire macro argument. This can be prevented. When grabbing tokens for an undelimited argument TeX discards explicit space-tokens until encountering a token that is not an explicit space token. What treatment of curly braces and space tokens surrounding components to split apart do you wish? E.g., what do you wish to obtain with `\def\sp{ }\edef\test{\noexpand\split{ { A } \noexpand\at\sp{ B } }}\test`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At 1st glimpse I had this idea, too, but that does not deliver the requested error message with things like `\split{Hello \at another \at World}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Ulrich, the example is artificial and is meant to be a MWE. I need to separate the argument into two parts to then manipulate them separately (making one italic and one bold, for example).

Comment: @UlrichDiez, I haven't actually thought about this case; so I am not sure what's the best solution. Ideally curly braces and spaces shouldn't matter, but I realize this might be difficult to achieve especially while enabling nesting. I also noticed that other solutions seem to not work for examples like `\split{A {\at B}}`. I plan define `\at` to issue a warning if it cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s argument processor to manage your request:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printsplit}{ +m +m }{%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}{~--~#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\split}{ > {\SplitArgument{1}{\at}} +m }{%
  \printsplit #1}

\begin{document}

\split{Hello \at \[ A \] \paragraph{Testing}

  \textit{worlds}

  Working!
}

% This is also OK
\split{\split{ Hello \at another} \at \split{ something \at World}}

\split{Hello}

%% and issue error for this one
%\split{Hello \at another \at World}

\end{document}
```

`> {\SplitArgument{1}{\at}} +m` allows for "long" `m`andatory arguments (with `\par`agraphs) to be split at `\at` up to a maximum of `1` such occurrences. Consequently, you'd expect there to be no split, or a single split. In the former case, the second argument passed to `\printsplit` will be `-NoValue-` that one can test for with a conditional `\IfValueT{#2}`.

Comment: @Tohiko: Sorry, I've updated my answer to fix this. Needed to check for `{\at}`, not `{ \at }`.

Comment: Great! This solution does everything and is easy enough for me to manipulate. Thank you! (might want to change `{ \at }` to `{\at}` in the explanation though). I am not sure how the other solutions compare, but they also all seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Split your argument at `\at`. This will only find `\at` at the outer level, so nesting `\split` is possible.

The name `\split` is not well-chosen, because you cannot load `amsmath` if you define it. Or define it if you load `amsmath`. But for this example it's fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\split}{+m}
 {
  \tohiko_split:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tohiko_split_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tohiko_split:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tohiko_split_seq { \at } { #1 }
  \int_case:nnF { \seq_count:N \l__tohiko_split_seq }
   {
    {0}{--}
    {1}{\seq_item:Nn \l__tohiko_split_seq { 1 } ~ -- ~ ??}
    {2}{\seq_item:Nn \l__tohiko_split_seq { 1 } ~ -- ~ \seq_item:Nn \l__tohiko_split_seq { 2 }}
   }
   {\msg_error:nn { tohiko/split } { too-many-at }}
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { tohiko/split } { too-many-at }
 {Too~many~\token_to_str:N \at\space tokens}
 {You~have~too~many~\token_to_str:N \at\space in~the~argument~to~split}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\split{Hello \at \[ A \] \paragraph{Testing}

  \textit{worlds}

  Working!
}

% This is also OK
\split{\split{ Hello \at another} \at \split{ something \at World}}

% % How to allow this form producing "Hello ???" for example
\split{Hello}

% % and issue error for this one
\split{Hello \at another \at World}

\end{document}
```

Console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./splitat.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./splitat.aux)

! Package tohiko/split Error: Too many \at tokens

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.46 \split{Hello \at another \at World}

? h

You have too many \at in the argument to split

?
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./splitat.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on splitat.pdf (1 page, 43559 bytes).
Transcript written on splitat.log.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this does what you want—instead of `\split` the command is named `\SplitAt` in order to avoid name-clashes with amsmath-stuff:

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToSecondAt{\long\def\UD@GobbleToSecondAt#1\at#2\at{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@AtSplit{\long\def\UD@AtSplit#1\at{#1 -- }}%
%You might prefer:
%\@ifdefinable\UD@AtSplit{\long\def\UD@AtSplit#1\at{#1-- }}%
\@ifdefinable\SplitAt{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\SplitAt[1]{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSecondAt#1\at\at}{\UD@AtSplit\UD@stopromannumeral#1\at???}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSecondAt#1\at}{\UD@AtSplit\UD@stopromannumeral#1}{%
        \UD@stopromannumeral
        \GenericError{}{Error: Too many \string\at\space tokens}{You have too many \string\at\space tokens in the argument to split.}{}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\SplitAt{Hello \at \[ A \] \paragraph{Testing}

  \textit{worlds}

  Working!
}

% This is also OK
\SplitAt{\SplitAt{ Hello \at another} \at \SplitAt{ something \at World}}

% % How to allow this form producing "Hello ???" for example
\SplitAt{Hello}

\message{^^J!!! The next error-message is what is wanted: !!!^^J}%
% % and issue error for this one
\SplitAt{Hello \at another \at World}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the penultimate line of the output:

You can see that each dash is surrounded by two spaces instead of one because the command neither does remove space tokens nor does remove curly braces that surround components that are to split apart while `\UD@AtSplit` inserts space-tokens that surround the dash.
Maybe you prefer not to have additional spaces surrounding the dashes inserted. In this case do:
`\@ifdefinable\UD@AtSplit{\long\def\UD@AtSplit#1\at{#1-- }}%`.